# Insertion of associative array into MySQL Database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array called `$output` which contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => J Arora
            [1] =>  India
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => J Ramuj
            [2] =>  Russia
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] =>  KJ Tris
            [2] =>  Germany
        )

)
```

How can i insert these data into mysql database table like these

```
---------------
name   | country
-------|---------
J Arora|India
-------|--------
J Ramuj|Russia
-------|--------
KJ Tris|Germany
-------|--------
```

I am not able to fetch these values separately from given array as their index are not in sequence.

Comment: simply you can use `foreach` loop to insert the same ? do want the insert query ?

Comment: What database abstraction layer are you using?

Comment: How do you know, what is the name and what is the country?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loop it with a `foreach`, and use PHP native functions like `current()` and `end()` to get your elements. Given that you just have two elements in your array at all times, this should work

```
foreach ($output as $v) {
    echo current($v); // Name
    echo end($v); // Country
}
```

Adapt this to build your query and execute it inside the loop. Inside the loop you could do

```
foreach ($output as $v) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (`name`, `country`) VALUES ('".current($v)."', '".end($v)."')";
    // TODO: Execute query
}
```

You should also note that any query using variables should be using prepared statements with placeholders. Both MySQLi and PDO supports this.

---

## Using prepared statements

Build the query before, and execute it as you loop it with the appropriate variables bound.

Example with PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`name`, `country`) VALUES (:name, :country)");
foreach ($output as $v) {
    $stmt->execute(array("name" => current($v), "country" => end($v));
}
```

---

Example with MySQLi:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`name`, `country`) VALUES (?, ?)");
foreach ($output as $v) {
    $name = current($v);
    $country = end($v);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $country);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of these functions.

Comment: The best approach is of course to use prepared statements - we're dealing with variables here. Updated my answer to reflect that with examples for both MySQLi and PDO.

Comment: Yes. I have used PS only.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your array user_details

```
foreach($user_detail as $single_user){
       $i = 0;
       foreach($single_user as $user){
           if($i==0){
             $name = $user;
           } else {
            $country = $user;
           } $i++;
       }
     $sql_query = INSERT into 'Table'($name, $country);
     //Execute this query as per mysqli or or mysql

}
```

//Considering that first value is always the name and 2nd values is always a country name

Comment: *I am not able to fetch these values separately from given array as their index are not in sequence.*

Comment: index of arrays are not in sequence. this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename(name,country) VALUES";

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($myarray);$i++){
  $sql.="(".$myarray[0].",".$myarray[1].")";
}
```

now execute `$sql`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($a=0; $a<count($array); $i++) {
    $dataArray=array_values($array[$i]);
    for ($j=0; $j<count($dataArray); $j++) {

        $name=$dataArray[0];
        $country=$dataArray[1];
        $insert_query="insert into tablename set name='$name', country='$country'";
        $res_query=mysql_query($insert_query);
    }
}
```

Hope this will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this can help. Its not tested.

```
$query = "INSERT into 'your table name' ('name', 'country') VALUES ";
foreach($yourArray as $data) {
    foreach($data as $d) {
       $query .= "('.$d[0].','.$d[1]),";
   }
}

$query = substr($query, 0, -1); // To remove last comma from query string
```

Then you can execute this query.